# Stop loading Jquery UI ajax tab content on each click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is there any way to stop loading the ajax content in Jquery UI tabs each time, when we click.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want not to load document every time using ajax. 
Than you can enable cache option true. 
It will only load document one time and save it in cache. 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cache

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking care of the ajax calls yourself  you can just save the

$ajax call in a variable like this:

```
var ajaxrequest = null;
```

... each time you change tabs, abort the previous call if it exists, then make the request

```
if(ajaxrequest){
   ajaxrequest.abort();
}
ajaxrequest = $.ajax(.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I think I've found the answer.

Just keep a list of the tabs that have been already loaded and cancel the load event if JQuery wants to load them again.

```
    var loaded = [];

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            if ($.inArray(ui.ajaxSettings.url, loaded) === -1) {
                loaded.push(ui.ajaxSettings.url);
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    };
```