# Caching for jQuery UI tab content loaded via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI tabs in my web application, and I am loading the tab content via ajax from external HTML files. The one drawback here is that any user input will be cleared when switching between tabs. Is it possible to enable caching in this situation to retain the user input? I tried adding `cache:true` to the example from the [jQuery site](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax):

```
    $(function() {
    $("#tabs")
        .tabs(
            {
                cache: true,
                beforeLoad : function(event, ui) {
                    ui.jqXHR
                        .error(function() {
                            ui.panel
                                .html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
                        });
                }
            });
    });
```

But when I switch from one tab to another and then back again, I am given the "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible." error.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: is your tab content in the same domain as your web app?

Comment: Well, I would say yes. My web application is a Spring MVC application, and the tab content files are within the same project...I am running the application on localhost.

Comment: I just tested this on my own webserver and a local file works fine but http://google.com fails. Just for fun, check to make sure the files you want to load are world readable.

Comment: It works correctly if I remove the whole beforeLoad function...

Comment: my test was run with jQuery 1.9.0 and jQueryUI 1.9.2. What versions are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop loading Jquery UI ajax tab content on each click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594191/stop-loading-jquery-ui-ajax-tab-content-on-each-click)